# Scala: implicitly consuming variable extracted as part of pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Given a method like this:

```
def toFun()(implicit a: Box) = a.toCircle()
```

As per my understanidng, at the moment, we need this syntax:

```
anObject match {
  case Another(a,b,c, _) =>
   implicit val tempA = a
   toFun()
  case YetAnother(a,b,_) =>
   implicit val tempA = a
   toFun()
}
```

Do we have some more intuitive syntax?

```
anObject match {
  case Another(implicit a,b,c, _) =>
   toFun()
  case YetAnother(implicit a,b,_) =>
   toFun()
}
```

**Update:**

I know we can do something like this:

```
anObject match {
  case Another(a,b,c, _) =>
   toFun()(a)
  case YetAnother(a,b,_) =>
   toFun()(a)
}
```

But in case of a method like:

```
def toFun()(implicit a: Box, b: Size, c: Context) = a.toCircle()
```

One will be required to do the following, defeating the purpose of implicits:

```
def main = {
  implicit context =>
    anObject match {
        case Another(a,b,c, _) =>
         toFun()(a,b, context)
        case YetAnother(a,b,_) =>
         toFun()(a,b,context)
     }
}
```

**Example:**

Please notice the `messageContext` and its usage

```
class Worker extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case m: MessageContext =>
        /**
        *
        *   Notice this
        */
        implicit val messageContext = m

        processor.processMessage{
            conversation =>
                val lastMessage = conversation.chat.last
                lastMessage.message match {
                    case Some(text) =>
                        if (text.contains("/search")) {
                            val searchArgs = text.trim.split("/search")
                            if (searchArgs.nonEmpty) {
                                val query = searchArgs.last.trim
                                system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(1800 milliseconds) {
                                    val activeContent = s"""
                                    Some content"
                                    |""".stripMargin)
                                    conversation.activeContent = activeContent
                                    processor.reply(s"""
                                    |Here are search results for "${query}":
                                    |${activeContent.mkString("\n------------\n")}
                                    |
                                    |""".stripMargin)
                                }
                                s"""Hello ${conversation.user.firstName}, we have received a search query for "${query}". We will soon respond with search results"""
                            } else {
                                s"""Hello ${conversation.user.firstName}, please enter a keyword post search command, i.e. "/search keyword"!"""
                            }
                        } else if (text.contains("/remind")) {
                            if (conversation.activeContent.isEmpty) {
                                "Please /search something first"
                            } else {
                                val remindArgs = (allCatch opt(text.split("/remind").last.trim.toInt)) // .split(" ")
                                if (remindArgs.isDefined) {     
                                    system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(5000 milliseconds) {
                                        /**
                                        *
                                        *   The above implicit is used here, if I pass it as an argument, then I will needed to pass other implciit arguments as well
                                        *   If I pass message as a standard argument, then the reply method looses it's simplciity, and please do factor in that
                                        *   we will need to call it at n number of times as the conversation tree grows
                                        */
                                        processor.reply(s"""Here's the reminder after 5 seconds for resource: ${conversation.activeContent(remindArgs.get - 1)}""")
                                    }             
                                    s"Hello ${conversation.user.firstName}, we would love to remind you about the resource: ${conversation.activeContent(remindArgs.get - 1)} "
                                } else {
                                    """Please enter valid index number, refer to search results. Use the number in begining of each search result item i.e. "/remind 1" or "/remind 2" or "/remind 5"!"""
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            conversation.activeTopic match {
                                case Some(topic)=>
                                    topic match {
                                        case Goal =>
                                        "Some message..."
                                        case ChangeTopic =>
                                            if (List("yes", "yeah", "yo", "yay", "y", "ya", "yepp", "why not").contains(text.toLowerCase.replace("!", ""))) {
                                                system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(5000 milliseconds) {
                                                    /**
                                                    *
                                                    *   Notice this
                                                    *   
                                                    */
                                                    processor.reply(s"""Yeah, we can change the topic""")
                                                }
                                                "Let me think if we are done here"
                                            }
                                            else {
                                            "Some message..."
                                            }
                                        case .......
                                    }
                                case _ => s"No active topic out there! Would you like to /start again?"
                            }
                        }
                    case None =>
                        conversation.activeTopic match {
                            case Some(topic)=>
                                topic match {
                                case GoalUploadPrompt =>
                                    lastMessage.raw.document match {
                                        case Some(doc) => doc.toString
                                        case None => lastMessage.raw.photo match {
                                            case Some(photo) => 
                                                "Some message..."
                                            case None => "Some message..."
                                        }
                                    }
                            case _ =>
                                "Some message..."
                            }
                            case None => "Some message...."
                        }
                }
            }(m, ws, token)
            case _ =>
        }
    }


object processor {
    def processMessage(cb: (BotConversation) => String)(implicit msg: MessageContext, ws: WSClient, token: String) = ?
}
```

Comment: You can also explicitly pass implicit parameter:  `toFun()(a)`

Comment: Yeah I know that one, it causes another issue in many cases, please see update.

Comment: What "another issue"?

Comment: @Dima please see update

Comment: @OldGaurd01`toFun()(a,b,implicitly[Context])`

Comment: Yeah @Dima somewhat similar to directly passing of the context variable, there should be a way where implicit work implicitly not by an explicit or proxy passing of variable

Comment: @OldGaurd01 no, `implicitly` is _not at all_ "similar to passing of the context variable": there is _no_ reference to the context variable here. The standard implicit resolution rules apply. Also, see my answer for a different option. Perhaps, that one is more to your liking.

Comment: Yeah, I got that point @Dima, what I am saying is one is required to pass these references or resolutions manually. I have tried potential solutions and after that thought of starting a thread that can inspire a bit of syntactical improvement on this side.

Comment: @OldGaurd01 the short answer is you are using implicits wrong. If you have to extract values from somewhere to specify them at call site, they should not really be implicit in the first place. So, the "correct" solution here would be making these parameters explicit. It would immediately resolve all the problems you mentioned. Short of that, you are going to _have to_ name the values you are passing in "manually", I don't really see anything in your variant that would be superior to the options suggested to you.

Comment: I am getting you and seems I chose a pretty trivial example. Will share a peace of code that will make sense. And maybe you could suggest how one could have written better code in first place. Thanks

Comment: @Dima check the added example and let me know if the code pattern used here is wrong or one is trying to make   hackish use of `implicit`

Comment: @OldGaurd01 Well, it's hard to be sure without seeing other uses for this function, but if they all look like this, then yes, I see no reason for `msg` to be implicit. And in any event, I see no reason you can't just pass it in explicitly in this code ... or to declare it as implicit once, like you did here. The choice seems to be a pure question of taste. Also don't see what it has to do with your original question. You just want to be able to write `case implicit m: MessageContext =>` instead of `case m: Messagecontext => implicit mc = m?` Oh well ... You can't :)

Comment: Thanks for getting my query, in last part of your comment and I believe it’s not XY problem as had I added this example directly here, it would have been considered as too specific requirement.

Comment: @OldGaurd01 it is an XYProblem by definition, because it is not about finding a solution for a specific practical issue (you have been given several of those here) but about fixating on a specific solution, that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you can always pass implicit parameters explicitly.
That's one possibility.

Alternatively, set your implicits first, then call:

```
    implicit val (a,b) = foo match {
      case Something(a, b, _) => a -> b
      case Another(a, b, _) => a -> b
    }
    toFun()
```

Or, to address another possibility brought up in comments:

```
     case foo match {
        case DoNothing => 
        case _ => 
             implicit val (a,b) = foo match {
                 case Something(a, b, _) => a -> b
                 case Another(a, b, _) => a -> b
             }
             toFun()
     }
```

In general, you can keep coming up with additional complications, but at some point it should just become apparent, that if you have to jump through so many hoops in order to supply your values implicitly, then maybe, they should not really be implicit in the first place?

Comment: This one is an interesting pattern, but will be very limiting as many a time we using pattern matching for branching of business logic/flow not just for parameter extraction. Think of one more case where there are no values, something like `case None => doNothing()`

Comment: @OldGaurd01 you are all over the place. This question is about passing implicits into aa function call. If there are no values, then there is no problem.

Comment: I didn't mean to make a point for sake of argument, I was really keen on knowing other people's thoughts around this. I re-read the title of the question, I have very clearly mentioned that I want to implicitly consume whatever if need to call a method, without any coded reference. I didn't mean to ask how to anyhow pass implicit marked parameters, because as a compromise we are already doing that.

Comment: @OldGaurd01 what we have here is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): it does not matter what you "want'. If you have a practical problem to solve, you are given a few solutions to that. If you just "want" to have a specific language feature for the sake of having it, you can go ahead and implement it :) Submit a pull request, see how it goes ...